# specific python if construct

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I'm trying to translate a Python utility to Ruby.
The problem is that don't understand python very well.

A fragment of the utility includes the following `if` conditional:

```
if bits&0x10==0x10:
```

What does that mean? bits is a variable. Is it some kind of "shortened" "&&", meaning if bits is nonzero **and** has the value 0x10? Thanks!

Comment: [bitwise "and"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

Comment: BTW, there is no `&&` in python, and `bits and 0x10==0x10` will do something quite different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually checks if the 5th bit of the variable bits is set

How it works

- & is bitwise anding.
- 0x10 is hex of binary value 0b10000
- So you do a bit wise anding of what ever is in `bits` with `0b10000`

Moreover, Ruby supports the similar construct for bit wise testing

```
if (bits&0x10)
    ......
end
```

Note as Tim mentioned, your Python construct can be simplified as

```
if bits&0x10:
    .......
```

Answer (score 6):

The `&` alone is the bitwise and operation. Ie, `bits` is compared with 0x10 bit by bit and if both have a bit of `1` for that position the result is `1` for that position, otherwise 0.

Basically, since 0x10 is 10000 in binary, this is checking if the 5th bit in `bits` is set to `1`.

I don't know much ruby, but my guess is, it should have a bitwise and operator and it would probably be `&` as well. Therefore this particular piece of code would end up being exactly the same in ruby.

Edit: according to the [Ruby Operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) page. Under section "Ruby Bitwise Operators", `&` acts as a bitwise and in ruby as well, so you can keep this as is in your translation of utility and it should, indeed, work.

Answer (score 0):

& is the binary bitwise "and" operator.

0x10 is hexadecimal 10.

You may want to read the python docs here

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html